# BASH, Merge two files, lower and upper triangular matrix, into one file

Tags: bash, matrix, awk, sed, grep

First file, file_utm:

```
1.3 3.5 2.8
    2.1 1.4
        0.5
```

Second file, file_ltm:

```
1.3
3.5 2.1
2.8 1.4 0.5
```

And one condition, when `if i=j; then i=j=0; fi`

Output file:

```
0 1.3 3.5 2.8
1.3 0 2.1 1.4
3.5 2.1 0 0.5
2.8 1.4 0.5 0
```

This is what I have tried:

```
#!/bin/bash
for (( x=1; x<=3; x++ ))
do
    awk -v var=$x 'NR==var' file_utm > ROW
    awk -v var=$x 'NR==var' file_ltm > COLUMN
    for (( y=1; y<=3; y++ ))
    do
        R=`awk -F  "\t" -v var=$y '{print $var}' ROW`
        C=`awk -F  "\t" -v var=$y '{print $var}' COLUMN`
        echo $R >> file
        echo $C >> file
        rm ROW
        rm COLUMN
    done
done
```

The other option that I have though is to fill a file with a matrix of only spaces, separate by tabs, and fill this matrix by given a value and addressing  the row and column positions. I know how to do it in C++, but not in bash and by using i.e. awk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Awk** solution:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{ a[NR+1]=$0 FS 0; next }{ sub(/^ +/,""); print (FNR==1)? 0:a[FNR],$0 }
     END{ print a[FNR+1] }' file_ltm file_utm
```

The output:

```
0 1.3 3.5 2.8
1.3 0 2.1 1.4
3.5 2.1 0 0.5
2.8 1.4 0.5 0
```

Comment: Thank you. But, when I tried it with two big files, it does not work. The ASCII files can be reached at: we.tl/TSBTSqacrj

Comment: @Another.Chemist, I does work for your current input from the question. I've observed the lines in your files - they have inconsistent/arbitrary number of columns and don't look as a part of one big matrix

Answer (score 1):

Reading the two files using file descriptor 5 and 6

```
# opening files descriptor for reading
exec 5< file_utm || exit 1
exec 6< file_ltm || exit 1

read -u5 up
echo "0 $up"
while read -u5 up; read -u6 low; [[ $low ]]; do
    echo "$low 0 $up"
done

# closing files
exec 5>&-
exec 6>&-
```